# Least squares estimate for a regression without intercept term

Tags: regression, least-squares, matrix

Using the least squares estimate, how do I calculate the estimate for $\beta$? For example, say I have the (small) dataset:

| Observation | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 | 3 |

How do I compute the least squares estimate of $\hat\beta$ while assuming the model $y=\beta x_1+\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is the error term?

Moreover, if I am trying to calculate $\hat\beta$ using the formula $\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, what would $X$ and $Y$ be in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is $r$ if it is not an intercept?

Comment: Thank you! $r$ would be the error term.

Comment: Please edit that information into the original post. // As a heads up, it is *extremely* common to denote the error term by $\epsilon$ ("\epsilon" between two dollar signs for $\LaTeX$ formatting).

Comment: Just fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work through your example.

$$
L(y,\beta) = \sum\bigg(
y_i - \beta x
\bigg)^2 = 
\bigg(
5-2\beta
\bigg)^2 + \bigg(
3-7\beta
\bigg)^2\\
=25-20\beta+4\beta^2 + 9 - 42\beta+49\beta^2\\
=34  - 62\beta + 53\beta^2
$$

The (square) loss function is $L = 34  - 62\beta + 53\beta^2$. Now take the derivative and set it equal to zero.

$$
\dfrac{dL}{d\beta} = 106\beta - 62 =0\\
\implies \beta = 62/106
$$

By the geometry, we know this is a minimum, though you can feel free to test the second derivative (a worthwhile exercise if you have not done it).

In matrix notation, we do the same as we usually would. Since there is no intercept, that usual column of $1$s is gone, so we simply wind up with $X = (2, 7)^T$, and the matrix algebra follows.

Since we know that the OLS solution is $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, we can skip the formal calculus and go right to this. More likely, though, we would do this calculation on a computer. In `R`, we specify that the intercept should be excluded with a command like `lm(y ~ 0 + x)`. Such a command agrees with the calculus-based solution.

```
x <- c(2, 7)
y <- c(5, 3)
L <- lm(y ~ 0 + x)
summary(L)
```

Comment: Very helpful, and thank you for the clarification. I think I get it now.